# copy files to java home directory in windows 7 access denied in java

Tags: java, windows-7

Access is denied when copy file to java home directory

```
FileUtils.copyFiletoDirectory(new File("somethingelsefilepath"),
   new File(System.getProperty("java.home"));
```

Comment: ... and that's fine. It should work if you start the application with admin privileges. But why do you want to do this?

Comment: may be the current user doesn't have permissions to copy file in that directory.

Comment: No need to downvote, guys. His approach is probably wrong but no need to give -1

Comment: i want to copy comm.jar file for serial port communication to javahome/jre/lib/ext/ through coding for deployment

Comment: java.home, system home, etc... not are good place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System directories are write protected (good). Any lib of any app must be in his app directory... (Good practices)

Good structure may be like:

**Windows**

```
C:\APPS\your.app.directory\
    .\bin\*.exe
    .\conf\*.xml
    .\lib\*.jar
```

**Linux**

```
/opt/your.app.directory/
    ./bin/*.sh
    ./conf/*.xml
    ./lib/*.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

`java.home` is the installation directory of Java. You shouldn't write anything to this directory. I guess you actually want to copy something to the user's home directory. In this case, the property is `user.home`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

Comment: i want to copy comm.jar file for serial port communication to javahome/jre/lib/ext/ through coding for deployment

Comment: You shouldn't. Do it when you install your application, or put it inside your application distribution ("lib" directory).